# HttpClient with dependency injection in Azure function

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#register-services) says to use  `builder.Services.AddHttpClient()` for registration 
HttpClient but I can resolve HttpClient without this.

I have a small startup where only register MyService :

```
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services.AddTransient<MyService>();
    }
}
```

and in Function, I want to resolve HttpClient and MyService and this code works.

```
public class Function
{
    public Function(MyService service, HttpClient client)
    {
    }

    [FunctionName("func")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Update(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = null)]
        HttpRequest request,
        ILogger logger)
    {
        return new OkObjectResult("Hello");
    }
}
```

- Who and where are register HttpClient?
- Should I use `builder.Services.AddHttpClient()`? Is this not redundant?

Answer (score 6):

You are right. You first need to register to it to the services:

```
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        //Register HttpClientFactory
        builder.Services.AddHttpClient();

        builder.Services.AddTransient<MyService>();
    }
}
```

If your Service will use the HttpClientFactory it is important to be register before the service. So when the MyService instance depedencies will be resolved there will already be a record for HttpCliendFactory in the DI container.

Your Function.cs class will then be:

```
public class Function
{
    private IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;
    private MyService _myService;


    public Function(MyService myService, IHttpClientFactory client)
    {
        _myService = myService;
        _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
    }

    [FunctionName("func")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Update(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = null)]
        HttpRequest request,
        ILogger logger)
    {
        //How to use example
        var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();

        return new OkObjectResult("Hello");
    }
}
```

HttpClient of course can be used without the client factory, but if you spawn HttpClient objects from the HttpClientFactory you will have a better out of the box management of your HttpClient resources.

Comment: Did it work for you? Do you need further assistance?